# How to verify the JComponents

Tags: java, swing, jcomponent, inputverifier

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
   String userName = userNameTxt.getText();
   char[] pass = password.getPassword();

}
```

I want to  validate the above fields( its username and password) I want to  take only alohabet(a-z) in username and a-z, 0-9 in password how to do this ? I am new to swing

Comment: please whats this question has something with html

Comment: @mKorbel: no this question has nothing with html

Comment: What does "verify" mean to you? What is wrong with the functionality of an InputVerifier? What type of functionality are you looking for?

Comment: Yup, what is it you are trying to do.  The answer is "yes" and "no"

Comment: Your edits makes your question clearer. Add a DocumentFilter to the text fields. This way you can prevent the user from entering unwanted characters. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Implementing a Document Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter) for more information.